# How can I remove lines in which length of a field exceeds some threshold using awk or sed?

Tags: sed, awk

I have the file *test.txt* similar to that:

```
aa:bbbbbb:22.3
a:bb:33.2
a:bbbb:22.3
aaaa:bb:39.9
```

I know how to count and sort them like:

```
awk -F ':' '{print $2}' test.txt | awk '{print length($0),$0}' | sort -nr
```

Now I want to remove the 1st and 3rd lines from the file because the length of the second field (containing "b") in those lines  is larger than 3. How can I do that using awk/sed? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `awk`:

This will output the lines whose 2nd field is >3:

```
$ awk -F: 'length($2)>3' file
aa:bbbbbb:22.3
a:bbbb:22.3
```

To do the opposite:

```
$ awk -F: 'length($2)<=3' file
a:bb:33.2
aaaa:bb:39.9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's so simple. I was looking too serious into the problem of recovering lines after my extracting command!

Comment: Thanks @Kent ;) I am in fact thinking on making this logo picture permanent haha

Answer (score 4):

Code for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed '/.*:..:.*/!d' file
```

or more general:

```
sed '/.*:.\{2\}:.*/!d' file
```